# Redirect with If/Else Statement vs Only the If

Tags: php, security

I am trying to keep my code as secure/clean as possible. If I have an If/Else statement that checks for whether or not the user is logged in (if not, the user is redirected back to the home page), will either of these methods work?

```
if (!$this->auth->is_logged_in()) {
    redirect('');
} else {
    // do something top secret
}
```

versus

```
if (!$this->auth->is_logged_in()) redirect('');
// do some top secret stuff
```

I would prefer the second method, but I am unsure if it is secure.

**Edit**
These would be used in a codeigniter controller

**Another Edit**
In codeigniter the `redirect()` function includes the `exit;` discussed in the answers below.

Comment: Wouldn't you need the `else` if you were to do some logic for a user which *is* logged in?

Comment: @Blender: If the user was not logged in, they would be redirected, and therefore the code after that wouldn't be ran.

Comment: @Blender If the user is logged in the function works just the same for both

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: Make sure that there is nothing echoed to the screen before this code block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no issue with security here.

I would remove the else if possible:

```
if (!$this->auth->is_logged_in()) {
    redirect('');
}
// top secret stuff
```

I think it's the  most readable.

Also, I'm sure it does, but make sure the redirect function includes a call to `exit`

Comment: @mtokoly: `exit;`  It stops the script from running.

Comment: After redirecting you should call `exit;`. It ends the processing of the script. It looks like you're using Code Igniter, and im sure CI includes exit;

Comment: Key point here is that calling "redirect" is not like returning from your function then and there; the redirect is set on the response, and the function continues.  So you call exit also.  Otherwise the top secret stuff will happen anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine, but braces are generally preferred in case you want to add functionality later.  I would also create a method in auth such as `gatekeeper()`, `force_login()`, whatever that does this check but redirects internally as you will probably use this a lot and it will be annoying to write this if statement check everywhere.