# Use of else statement vs unused assignment

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a similar question to the one posted [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860691/redirect-with-if-else-statement-vs-only-the-if)

I have an if statement in an mvc controller that looks like this:

```
if (submitButton != "Search")
{
ModelState.Clear();
}
TempData["searchParameter"] = searchParameter;
```

however if the condition is false, TempData["searchParameter"] is never used. Is it a better practice to leave the code as above or put the TempData["searchParameter"] assignment in an else statement?

Comment: TempData["searchParameter"] = searchParameter; will be set regardless of the value of submitButton in the posted code, unless it is wrapped in another condition.

Comment: Do you mean it's never used *after* you assign it a value?

Comment: @Jon yes, given that the condition is false searchParameter would be null so the existence of TempData["searchParameter"] is pointless

Comment: Why don't you put it *in* the `if` block then? Or did you actually mean if the condition is *true* the value is never used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in an `else` statement.

It makes the logic flow more explicit and an unnecessary operation is omitted, which affects the performance positively.

Comment: +1. I would add that `TempData["searchParameter"] = ...` is not just an "assignment" in terms of setting the value of some local variable, so it cannot be optimized away by the jit or the compiler, it's a lot more costly, and the effects are more far-reaching. In this case, it involves the session and could continue to have an effect on the next request from that client!

Answer (score 0):

Id use the else statement.  Makes it clearer and securer if any changes are made in the future.

I guess its also good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `TempData["searchParameter"]` is assigned to regardless of of whether `submitButton != "Search"`. Is this the behaviour you are expecting?

If not, an `else` statement will resolve this for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, running unnecessary code is never a good idea when it can be easily avoided. It may not seem like a big deal in this case, but it is not a good habit to get into.

More generally, I always use an else statement even when the code flow would be identical without it. For example:

```
if(null == foo) {
  return false;
} else {
  foo.Bar();
  return true;
}
```

The else is not strictly necessary, and some code analysis tools will recommend removing it. But I prefer the explicitness of being able to tell just by glancing at the structure of the code that only one of those blocks is actually going to be executed. Without the else, you have to analyze the first block to determine that it is exclusive of the second block.